# html and php fill subject line from contact form

Tags: php, html, web, html-email, subject

So I have created a page which includes several hyperlinks to web forms (for eg. volvo would link to a form that emails to volvo website, saab would link to form that emails to saab form) however I am having a bit of trouble changing the subject line. Rather than create 8 or 9 different php send email files. Can I simply change the subject line from the form? Here is what I was trying but can't get it going? I just want to take the heading from my form and use that to fill in the subject line each time.

php file that sends email

```
$email_subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

html file with form

```
<h1 name="subject" value="Volvo Interest">Volvo Form</h1>
```

I dont know if it is needed but here is my mailer header as well

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Using these I just get (no subject)

Comment: `<h1>` is not a valid input nor will POST accept it.

Comment: So, what exactly "do" you want? Given the answer and the comment you left in there. [*"Although that gives me another input box though? Its actually the reason I tried taking it from the heading."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032911/html-and-php-fill-subject-line-from-contact-form#comment75092718_44032944) - Your question is starting to look unclear and may get voted to close as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so to have a SUBJECT variable sent to the PHP script without having a visible input textbox, you can simply use this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Volvo Form: <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Volvo Interest">
</form>
```

Oh and if your PHP is at a different location than your HTML form, then don't forget to specify the **action="your_php_file_location_here.php"** instead of leaving it blank, which will submit to the same location the browser is at when filling out the form.

... and from what I think I understand of your question, you do not want hackers to modify that variable before it reaches the PHP script, so in this case, I would NOT suggest you put the words "Volvo Interest" in the input.  Instead go with a number like this in the **HTML form**:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Volvo Form: <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="3">
</form>
```

... then in your **PHP script**, use a switch/case statement to select the proper words to use for the subject.  This way, people cannot modify your words:

```
switch($_POST['subject']){
case 1:
$email_subject = "Acura Interest";
break;
case 2:
$email_subject = "Saab Interest";
break;
case 3:
$email_subject = "Volvo Interest";
break;
// case 4: ...
default: // Just in case somebody sends a number case that does not exist
$email_subject = "Unknown Interest";
}
```

Comment: GOSH-DARN, the editor stripped my first sentence.  I was saying: Form elements should begin with <input NOT <h1 :)

Comment: never mind the `<h1>`, it's' ok as it is now. I edited for you. Use ticks `\`` to highlight code.

Comment: Haaa! Thank you kind sir :D

Comment: To add to this answer: If you don't want the user to be able to change the subject line you can add the 'disabled' attribute to the input and give it a class so you can style it with some CSS.

Comment: Although that gives me another input box though? Its actually the reason I tried taking it from the heading.

Comment: @JoeHigley I would totally go against this practice.  If OP wants to disable subject modification, he should 100% do that in the PHP script, not in the browser, because ANY web page can be 100% modified through the browser console so the disabled attribute could be removed in 1 second.

Comment: @MrE What do you mean ANOTHER input box? Make sure you DO NOT have a </input> end tag, since inputs do NOT require this.  If not, please post your code, you should have only 1 <input> and zero </input>

Comment: Volvo Form<input disabled name="subject" value="Volvo Interest">

Comment: This adds an input box but greys it out, is there a way to do it without the input box being added

Comment: Can you put the whole thing online? A part of your code that duplicates the input box is yet to be seen.  What you just posted cannot display 2 different boxes.  Your additional box is somewhere else than in the code we see at the moment.

Comment: What I mean is, I dont want any input box. Apologies if I've made the explanation more confusing than it needed to be. I just wanted to take the heading of the form and use that as the subject line of the email

Comment: Then, what you want is not a <input, it's a <input type="hidden" see my modified answer above :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Working perfectly now, apologies for the noob in the crowd haha. Only doing stuff like this for practice. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I've just edited my answer, please check it out, it's a little bit more secure than what you planned on doing initially, please consider doing that instead of directly passing words in the variable.